# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
at module.exports (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at handleParseError (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
at module.exports (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at S:\ecommercesite\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}